# Monty hall problem returning results of 33% for both switching and not switching

Tags: python

So I've been trying to model a problem similar to the Monty hall problem in python and I expected switching to yield winning results of 66% but that's not the case. Could someone please point out where I've gone wrong? I'm trying to conclude the percentage wins of winning and losing depending on switching. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

#Ask the user for how many runs
runs = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate?"))
switchwins, nonswitchwins, switchlosses, nonswitchlosses = 0, 0, 0, 0

# Get the random number started with a seed
random.seed()

#run once for user switching and once for user not switching
for swap in True,False:
# Do everything for the number of runs we have
for i in range(runs):

    # Setup the prize locations
    prizes = ['nothing', 'nothing', 'coin']
    # Randomly mix them up
    random.shuffle(prizes)

    #select a random location
    ChoiceA = random.randrange(3)

    # print("Before the prize is revealed, I will show you what is in one of the other hiding places")

    # remove one of the other hiding places which has nothing as a prize and isn't ChoiceA
    for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
        if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents == "nothing":
            showlocation = currentlocation
            # print("There is nothing in this location", showlocation)
            break


    if swap:
        #swap to the other location
        for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
            if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents != showlocation:
                swap_to = currentlocation

        # check if the swapped choice is a win
        if prizes[swap_to] == "coin":
            switchwins +=1
        else: 
            switchlosses +=1
    # when not swapping locations check for win
    else:
        if prizes[ChoiceA] == "coin":
            nonswitchwins +=1
        else: 
            nonswitchlosses +=1

print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", 
round((switchwins/runs)*100,1), "%")

print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", 
round((nonswitchwins/runs)*100,1),"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents != showlocation:`, but isn't it rather `if currentlocation != ChoiceA and currentlocation != showlocation:`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small bug in you code. Very minor but it is causing your error. In your first if-statement of the `if swap` block you should replace `if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents != showlocation` with `if currentlocation != ChoiceA and currentlocation != showlocation`.

Rememeber that your variable `contents` is a string whilst `showlocation` is an integer, I I don't think the is the comparison that you mean to make. I believe you want to set `to_swap` to be the third index value that wasn't chosen initially nor shown to the player.

Here is your code with this change implemented.

```
import random

#Ask the user for how many runs
runs = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate?"))
switchwins, nonswitchwins, switchlosses, nonswitchlosses = 0, 0, 0, 0

# Get the random number started with a seed
random.seed()

#run once for user switching and once for user not switching
for swap in True,False:
    # Do everything for the number of runs we have
    for i in range(runs):

        # Setup the prize locations
        prizes = ['nothing', 'nothing', 'coin']
        # Randomly mix them up
        random.shuffle(prizes)

        #select a random location
        ChoiceA = random.randrange(3)

        # print("Before the prize is revealed, I will show you what is in one of the other hiding places")

        # remove one of the other hiding places which has nothing as a prize and isn't ChoiceA
        for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
            if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents == "nothing":
                showlocation = currentlocation
                # print("There is nothing in this location", showlocation)
                break


        if swap:
            #swap to the other location
            for currentlocation, contents in enumerate(prizes):
                if currentlocation != ChoiceA and currentlocation != showlocation:
                    swap_to = currentlocation

            # check if the swapped choice is a win
            if prizes[swap_to] == "coin":
                switchwins +=1
            else: 
                switchlosses +=1
        # when not swapping locations check for win
        else:
            if prizes[ChoiceA] == "coin":
                nonswitchwins +=1
            else: 
                nonswitchlosses +=1

print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", 
round((switchwins/runs)*100,1), "%")

print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", 
round((nonswitchwins/runs)*100,1),"%")
```

The output I get with this change is:

```
How many games do you want to simulate?100000
This is the number of wins if the user switched 66.7 %
This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch 33.3 %
```

which is what you would expect for the Monte Hall problem

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, this problem could be easily solved with a debugger or a small test suite. The program is just a big wall of code and these things are easy to miss. Would be more obvious if the code were broken down to functions.

This line doesn't seem to make sense:

```
if currentlocation != ChoiceA and contents != showlocation:
    ...
```

seems like it should be:

```
if currentlocation != ChoiceA and currentlocation != showlocation:
    ...
```

A simpler alternative is to replace that `if` statement and its enclosing `for` statement with a little set operation:

```
showlocation = (set(range(3)) - {ChoiceA, showlocation}).pop()
```